# FindControl() from UserControl inside a for loop

Tags: .net, user-controls, for-loop, findcontrol

I'm creating a usercontrol that will have a series of LinkButtons.

I've declared all of my link buttons at the top of my class

```
LinkButton LB1 = new LinkButton();
LinkButton LB2 = new LinkButton();
//...
LinkButton LB9 = new LinkButton();
```

now I'd like to be able to create a loop to access all of those link buttons so I don't have to write them all out every time.

I tried something like this within my overridden CreateChildControls() method:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)FindControl("LB" + i.ToString());
            lb.Text = i.ToString() + "-Button";
        }
```

I keep getting an exception saying that lb.Text... is not set to an instance of an object.

I also tried giving all of my LB1, LB2 etc valid Ids.

ie: LB1.ID = "LB1";

still not dice.

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindControl` only works once those controls have been added to `Controls` collection, and that only happens inside the `OnInit` method. So you're getting an exceptions because the LB1, LB2, etc controls haven't been added to the Controls collection and FindControl is returning `null`.

One way you could do it is have a `List<LinkButton>`, then in your `Init` event handler, add the controls to the list.

Another way, you could use LINQ to loop through your child controls:

```
var ctrls = Controls.OfType<LinkButton>();
```

This version would return *all* `LinkButton` controls, so I'm not sure if that's exactly what you want. Again, this would only work in the `Init` event or later in the page cycle.

**Additionally**

Depending on how your page is structure, you might be better off using a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) control. Something like this on your .aspx/ascx file:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btn" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then in your code behind, you'd use data-binding to set up the array and so on.

Comment: ya you were spot on.  As soon as I added them in my createchildcontrols, it works as intended.  I was sorta hoping I could add them dynamically...but that won't work so I guess I'll just have to show/hide them dynamically.

I'll mark this as the answer, but if you can provide some suggestions as to how I can add them dynamically, that'd be swell :)

Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a bit of info about the Repeater control, which might help you to simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

is it definitely finding the LinkButton? It looks to me like FindControl isn't actually finding the LinkButton.

Hook up the debugger and check that lb isn't actually null.

Answer (score 0):

I think FindControl only returns controls within an immediate container, so if you have them inside of say a DIV element or a table, then it will not find them. You can use a helper function similar to the following:

```
public static Control FindControl(Control start, string id)
{
  Control foundControl;
  if (start != null) 
  {
    foundControl = start.FindControl(id);
    if (foundControl != null) 
      return foundControl;

    foreach (Control c in start.Controls) 
    {
      foundControl = FindControl(c, id);
      if (foundControl != null) 
        return foundControl;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

You can then pass this or a specific container as a start parameter.

Comment: That's only true if the `<div>` or `<table>` (etc) have `runat="server"`.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
    int btnCount = 10;
    LinkButton[] btns = new LinkButton[btnCount];
    for (int i = 1; i <= btnCount; i++)
    {
        btns[i - 1] = new LinkButton(){
            Text = string.Format("{0} - Button", i) 
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Alek and @codeka mentioned, FindControl will only work once they have been added to a container, such as a Page object.

What you can do is instead of declaring them each as variables, add them to a List instead, like so:

```
var linkButtonList = new List<LinkButton>();
linkButtonList.Add(new LinkButton());
linkButtonList.Add(new LinkButton());
etc..
```

then you can loop through the List easily whenever you need to access all of the LinkButton controls:

```
foreach (var item in linkButtonList)
{
    // do something with the LinkButton here...
}
```

Comment: cool thanks.  I ended up going with something close to this.
thanks again.